# New unwanted/unidentifed connection using NoMachine

Tags: linux, windows, remote-access, nomachine

New unidentified/unwanted connection appears in my windows Nomachine. 3-5 minutes after a start it is here:
[image]
after couple minutes it disappears:
[image]
The connection is configured with an IP address from my work network and mask.

Incoming connections are disabled.
What does it mean when the connection logo has 3 joined pipes in the lower right corner instead of the "!M" symbol?

What does this connection mean? Should I look for the signs of intrusion into my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three joined pipes indicates a computer that is being broadcast on your local network: See figure 3 in the tutorial here: https://www.nomachine.com/finding-other-nomachine-computers-on-the-same-network.

The sessions with the !M symbol are your traditional connections already started.  See fig 4 in the same tutorial.